# Laravel 5.2 $errors vazio

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, validação, framework

Estou usando o Laravel 5.2 e estou tentando criar uma validação para registro de usuario.

Em UserController.php tenho:

```
public function postSignUp(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'first_name' => 'required|max:120',
        'password' => 'required|min:4'
    ]);
    ...
}
```

E na View para o SignUp tenho:

```
@if(count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <ul>
                @foreach($errors->all as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Porém ao tentar registrar um usuário com email já existente ou até mesmo sem colocar nenhum texto nos inputs, a div **.col-md-6** é criada mas não retorna nada.

Dei um var_dump em $errors e aparece isto:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag)[133]
  protected 'bags' => 
array (size=1)
  'default' => 
    object(Illuminate\Support\MessageBag)[134]
      protected 'messages' => 
        array (size=3)
          ...
      protected 'format' => string ':message' (length=8)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está chamando `$errors->all`. Isso você está chamando uma propriedade de MessageBag, que não existe.

Na verdade, você deve chamar o método `MessageBag::all()`. Assim:

```
@foreach( $errors->all() as $error)
  <li>{{ $error }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Entenda que `MessageBag` não é um `array`, e sim um objeto. Você só consegue usar a função `count` na variável `$errors`, pois `MessageBag` implementa a interface `Countable`.

Se quiser entender mais sobre o funcionamento dessa classe, veja:

https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html

Comment: Realmente, voce está correto ! Foi um erro de sintaxe que me passou despercebido. No caso faltava os parenteses depois do all. Muito obrigado !